# Can't find ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370 driver for Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit on HP Pavilion DV7-4285dx

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, 64-bit

I've got an HP Pavilion DV7-4285dx that has switchable graphics between some generic Intel card and the discrete card, an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370. I'd like to be able to use that ATI card for high performance graphics on my laptop in Ubuntu but when I try to use the fglrx drivers, it still says that only the Intel card is being used. I installed AMD's ATI Radeon HD 63xx series drivers but that led to Ubuntu booting and going attempting to go into "Low graphics mode" which ended up just freezing on the "low graphics mode" selection screen, so I went into ctrl+alt+f1 console and reinstalled the fglrx driver so I could reboot into Linux. I assume it didn't work because my card is the ATI Mobility Radeon HD6370 which is apparently not the same as ATI Radeon HD 63xx series.

Now that you know my life story, has anybody been able to get the ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370 working in Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, or any other version of Ubuntu for that matter?

Thanks in advance 
-Rob

Comment: Maybe they have something for 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this how to and it should help you install the driver at the

[AMD Linux Community](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide)